# Code will only read the first line of a text file

Tags: python

So I copied some code over from another post on here, but i cant get it to read any lines after the first, im trying to make a username and password system.

```
def register():                                     #This function has been adapted from www.stackoverflow.com
    print("Please register.")
    time.sleep(1)
    username = input("Please input your desired username: ")
    password = input("Please input your desired password: ")
    file = open("outputusernamefile.txt","a")
    file.write(username)
    file.write(" ")
    file.write(password)
    file.write("\n")
    file.close()
    print("Please login now.")
    time.sleep(1)
    logged = True
    login()


def login():                                        #This function has been adapted from www.stackoverflow.com
    print("Please enter your credentials.")
    time.sleep(1)
    login.username = str(input("Please enter your username: "))
    password = str(input("Please enter your password: "))
    for line in open("outputusernamefile.txt","r+").readlines(): # Read the lines
        login_info = line.split() # Split on the space, and store the results in a list of two strings
        if login.username == login_info[0] and password == login_info[1]:
            print("Correct credentials!")
            print("You are now logged in.")
            logged = True
            QuizStart()
            return True
        else:
            print("Incorrect credentials.")
            print("Please try again.")
            time.sleep(0.5)
            login()
            return False
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're quitting the loop in the very first iteration. That's why only one line is being checked. Perhaps try to do something like this.

```
def login():
    ...
    with open("outputusernamefile.txt","r+") as file:
        for line in file.readlines():
            login_info = line.split() # Split on the space, and store the results in a list of two strings
            if login.username == login_info[0] and password == login_info[1]:
                print("Correct credentials!")
                print("You are now logged in.")
                logged = True
                QuizStart()
                return True

    print("Incorrect credentials.")
    print("Please try again.")
    time.sleep(0.5)
    login()
```

Comment: how would i change that? im not exactly experienced.

Answer (score 1):

The recursive call in the `login` function starts reading the file from the beginning because the file is opened again.

You need to read the entire file, searching for a match, and then make the final decision at the end of the loop.  You can only return early if the function finds the requested user name.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how it works for me. You forgot to iterate over the lines one by one.

```
import time

def register():                                     #This function has been adapted from www.stackoverflow.com
    print("Please register.")
    time.sleep(1)
    username = input("Please input your desired username: ")
    file = open("outputusernamefile.txt","a")
    file.write(username)
    file.write(" ")
    password = input("Please input your desired password: ")
    file.write(password)
    file.write("\n")
    file.close()
    print("Please login now.")
    time.sleep(1)
    logged = True
    login()


def login():                                        #This function has been adapted from www.stackoverflow.com
    print("Please enter your credentials.")
    time.sleep(1)
    login.username = str(input("Please enter your username: "))
    password = str(input("Please enter your password: "))
    with open("outputusernamefile.txt","r+") as file: # Read the lines
        line = file.readline()
        while line:
            login_info = line.split() # Split on the space, and store the results in a list of two strings
            if login.username == login_info[0] and password == login_info[1]:
                user_found = True
                print("QuizStart()")
                return True
            else:
                time.sleep(0.5)
                user_found = False
            line = file.readline()

    if not user_found:
        print("Incorrect credentials.")
        print("Please try again.")
        login()
    else:
        print("Correct credentials!")
        print("You are now logged in.")


register()
```